# Is I2C ack bit supposed to be one when it's reading data? Why is my ack bit different from TI doc (Understanding the I2C Bus)

Tags: i2c

The following is the ack bit I observed from my oscilloscope. It looks like there is a glitch in ack.

[image: glitch]
[image: start stop]

[image: float]

Next figure is what I found from the [Texas Instrument document SLVA704: "Understanding the I2C Bus" by Jonathan Valdez and Jared Becker](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slva704/slva704.pdf):

[image: Example of Single Byte Data Transfer]

Comment: kile - Hi, To help give readers more context about the configuration of the I2C bus being shown in this question, I guess it is the same configuration described in your previous question: [FPGA - SCL of I2C is always high when it's in reading mode](/q/688298). Is that correct? Thanks.

Comment: @SamGibson  Yes, the rest is the same as what I mentioned before.

Comment: kile - Thanks for confirming. Since you now have 2 questions open & active on the same project, please ensure that they are as separate & self-contained as possible and avoid overlap (or where unavoidable, disclose the overlap with other question(s)). Otherwise there's a risk that one question gets closed as a duplicate of the other, and/or a risk of annoying site members who discover important info in one question, which causes them to waste time in the other one etc. Thanks. (In general, having multiple active questions on the same topic is a risky plan. I hope you can navigate it here.)

Comment: The ACK bit being high at the end of your data read is perfectly normal. It's the I2C Master (your FPGA) telling the Slave that this is the end of the read operation. If the Master were wanting to read additional data then it would pull ACK low at that point and then read the next byte.

Comment: Also - in the the 2nd pic in your question it's clear that you still have your FPGA's I2C pins operating in push-pull mode, which was explained to be wrong in your other question. You need to configure them for open-drain mode so that they only ever actively drive low, and let your I2C pull-up resistors pull high. This isn't obvious in your 3rd pic - so maybe you've fixed it there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the ACK bit is fine.

The FPGA is still holding SDA low while slave pulls SDA low on falling SCK.

The FPGA then releases SDA while slave is pulling low, which is why there is a small step higher as slave has weaker output.

The FPGA then sends rising and falling clock edges and slave immediately releases SDA high after falling edge, before FPGA prepares to send the next bit.

So that's not a glitch, that's how it is supposed to look like, if bus is left floating.

Comment: Please check the updated ack figure when it's reading data

Comment: @kile That's the same problem I explained yesterday. The rising edges have overshoots which tells the FPGA pushes the lines high as outputs, which is not allowed. The ACK is faulty like yesterday because FPGA keeps SDA as high output when slave tries to pull the line down, which explains why 3.3V drops to about 3.0V as the output drivers are fighting agains each other.

Comment: What should I do if I want to read? The R/W bit has to be 1 in order to be in read mode

Comment: @kile The secret is, never allow any I2C pin to become output which is high. Only output low which pulls the wire to 0V, or release it as high impedance state when pull-up resistor pulls it high.

Comment: I have now successfully did what you said as secret. But ack bit is still missing when it' read. Please see my third oscilloscope picture.

Comment: @kile Then it means your FPGA is not sending the ACK to slave when reading data. If you want to read more data then send ACK to slave, and NAK the last byte when you are finished.

Comment: What's more, the data I received from slave is not correct. Because I have previously written data that this should be 0x50 instead of 0x00. What's more, what do you mean nak? is it one?

Comment: @kile What you have written somewhere and how you are reading it back is not seen in the pictures and you may be doing it wrong. You need to show that. Yes ACK bit low is ACK, ACK bit high is Not Acknowledged or NAK. Start a new question about that, this question is solved already.

Answer (score 4):

Looks fine to me. SDA is low during the 9th CLK pulse, that means ACK. It is then released by the slave at the falling edge of 9th CLK and goes high, that is normal. Why does it look lie to you that there is a glitch?

Comment: Please see my updated picture.

Comment: Please have a look at the updated ack when it's reading data